# GitHub oAuth with FirebaseUI on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Implemented authorization with this tutorial
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#github

And it wasn't working. For an unknown reason.

Will provide an answer below.

I see no reason to provide my code since tutorials are full of them and i'm totally followed them.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, i just found a guide which not listed in the instruction. Or it's really hard to find.
Hope this helps someone.

After you have done with hosting and add

```
.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

It's not `"Congrats, you did it!"` as mentioned in the tutorial.

The second guide i mentioned above
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#web-assoc
You need to complete the next step: `"Confirm the Digital Asset Links files"`.

And for inattentive ones as me, want to add, **not** just copy-paste code snippet, it has spaces and you have to remove it.
In another case you will get something like this `statements:list?%20source` and you will get an error as a response.

In my case, all worked only after i did that step.

*If FirbaseUI team read it and it was helpful, please add plus one step in your guide to avoid misunderstanding.*